# Java LocalDate doesn't accept all EpochDay field valid values

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY.range().getMinimum());
```

This code above finish with the following stack trace thrown:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -1000018564
  at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:330)
  at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
  at java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(LocalDate.java:341)
```

I did not understand why this instruction is unsupported.

Actually, java-time strategy is query the own Temporal its `ValueRange` for an`TemporalField` through `range (TemporalField)` method. And, for this case `LocalDate` does not change the EpochDay field default range.

```
@Override
public ValueRange range(TemporalField field) {
    if (field instanceof ChronoField) {
        ChronoField f = (ChronoField) field;
        if (f.isDateBased()) {
            switch (f) {
                case DAY_OF_MONTH: return ValueRange.of(1, lengthOfMonth());
                case DAY_OF_YEAR: return ValueRange.of(1, lengthOfYear());
                case ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH: return ValueRange.of(1, getMonth() == Month.FEBRUARY && isLeapYear() == false ? 4 : 5);
                case YEAR_OF_ERA:
                    return (getYear() <= 0 ? ValueRange.of(1, Year.MAX_VALUE + 1) : ValueRange.of(1, Year.MAX_VALUE));
            }
            return field.range();
        }
        throw new UnsupportedTemporalTypeException("Unsupported field: " + field);
    }
    return field.rangeRefinedBy(this);
}
```

EpochDay field valid values should be transformable to `LocalDate`, otherwise why long is it in the range?

The same occurs with `Instant` and `INSTANT_SECONDS` field: `Instant.ofEpochSecond(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS.rangeRefinedBy(Instant.now()).getMinimum());`

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: This works in Java 10, but fails in Java 8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Java 8 Update 181 at least, fixed by Java 10 at least.

## Java 10 - Pass

Works for me, [Java 10.0.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [Zulu JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems#Zulu_and_Zulu_Embedded_JVM) by [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems), on [macOS High Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra).

```
LocalDate ld = 
    LocalDate.ofEpochDay( 
        ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY.range().getMinimum() 
    )
;
System.out.println( ld );
```

> -999999999-01-01

## Java 8 - Fail

Throws exception on Java 1.8.0_181, [Zulu JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems#Zulu_and_Zulu_Embedded_JVM) by [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems), on [macOS High Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra).

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -1000018564
>       at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:330)
>       at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
>       at java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(LocalDate.java:341)

The offending line seems to be # 341 in the `LocalDate.java` file.

```
int year = YEAR.checkValidIntValue(yearEst);
```

…where `yearEst` is -1000018564